# When using DDMS to connect to debugger, sometimes breakpoints are ignored

Tags: android, eclipse, breakpoints, ddms

When using DDMS to manually connect the debugger to a running process by selecting the process and clicking the debug icon, sometimes all breakpoints are ignored.  LogCat reports Debugger is active.

This problem occurs frequently but not consistently.  The only workaround I have is to start the process from the beginning in debug mode.

Has anyone else seen this problem and come up with a better workaround?